# Determining variance of an U.M.V.U.E

Tags: self-study, unbiased-estimator

Given $X_1...X_n$ i.i.d. Bernoulli R.V.s with parameter $\theta$, I found an UMVUE for $\tau(\theta)=\theta^2+\theta$ with Rao-Blackwellization. That process seemed fairly straight-forward to me, and I ended up with $\frac{T(n+T-2)}{n(n-1)}$, where T is the number of successes and n is the number of trials. Second, I calculated the Cramer-Rao lower bound and wound up with $\frac{(4\theta^2+4\theta+1)(\theta(1-\theta))}{n}$. I'd like to plot these both and see if the UMVUE attains the CRLB, but to do that I need to find the variance of my UMVUE!

I imagine I want to go about this as $E([\mathrm{umvue}]^2) - E([\mathrm{umvue}])^2$, and I already know that $E([\mathrm{umvue}])$ is $\theta^2 + \theta$, since its unbiased. However the second moment is confusing me greatly; in fact I have no idea how to approach it. Am I missing something obvious? 
Thanks for the help!
(And please let me know if there is anything I should clarify!)

I finished up the question, and it did indeed involve the 4th and 3rd moments of the binomial. Should anyone ever encounter a similar problem, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialDistribution.html contains the 1st through 4th moments of the distribution, which should save you a great deal of computation!

Comment: $T \sim {\rm Binomial}(n,\theta)$ so, assuming your initial derivation is correct, the challenge is calculating the third and fourth moments of a binomial distribution. For this, its [moment generating function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function), $m(t) = (1-\theta+\theta e^t)^n$, may be useful.

Comment: Indeed, that was my fear (that fourth moment is nasty!) - I was hoping I was missing some workaround, but oh well. Appreciate the help!

Comment: I'm glad to see you figured out the answer, @SammyJ. If you get a chance, please consider posting your answer below for future reference and so the question comes off of the "unanswered" list.